# Accessing Express's locals in client-side JS

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

There are a few posts on this topic already but I can't get it to work on my code :(

I have this simple rendering function:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index", {
    route: "one"
  });
});
```

I try to access this variable `route` in client side js file to no luck so far:

```
// Unexpected token: <
var route = <%- JSON.stringify(route) %>;

// variable 'route' is undefined
var route = !{route};

// Unexpected token .
var route = !{JSON.stringify(route)};

// console log out "<%- JSON.stringify(route) %>;
var route = "<$- JSON.stringify(route) %>";
```

Please note that my view engine is `ejs`

Comment: You can't use `ejs` inside javascript files. You need to create a `script` block in your view file.

Comment: @BrianGlax: it works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you try:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index", JSON.stringify({
    route: "one"
  }));
});
```

and use JSON.parse in client side

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: The problem is using `route` in a client-side JS file. Also, `body-parser` has nothing to do with this :-)